# Checks if a string value is real Boolean type

Tags: java, boolean

I am having some string values which converted by using Boolean.parseBoolean. Then I realised that doing validation ,  it will return true where input is true (case insensitive). Every other value will return false, including null or an any other string, Example: hello.  Then I did the logic as follow:

```
        String input = entityDto().constantValues.get("input");
        String message = ("Boolean entity contains invalid data: " + input);
        if (input != null) {
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException(message);
```

It looks fine , but however I am wondering if there is any better way to handle the real boolean check?
I need is to validate that the input is either true or false (case insensitive). Otherwise throw a IllegalStateException. Like type: boolean represents two values: true and false. Note that truthy and falsy values such as "true", "", 0 or null etc are not considered boolean values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the code is expressing exactly what its intention is, I would only put the message directly in the constructor of the exception - no need for the variable and maybe merge the `if`s || only alternative I would consider is testing directly for `"true"` and `"false"`, without using `parseBoolean()` at all

Comment: Oh, and I would not use `IllegalStateException` ("Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time") but maybe `IllegalArgumentException` or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 1.8, "[Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)" was added to the Java language. This structure can be used in many different cases.

For example:

- To express data can be null. (Optional<Account>)
- Wrapping. " Optional.of(account).filter(AccountValidator::isValid).orElse(null) "
- before wrapping null check "
  Optional.ofNullable(customer).map(this::getId).orElse(null) "

... There are many benefits to using Optional.

Here, you can use it for clarity. When I look at your code, It is seen as small but "if cases" make it difficult to read your code. You can hide them with Optional and your code will be more practical

You can use it alternatively

```
    return Optional.ofNullable(value)
            .filter(parseValue -> "true".equalsIgnoreCase(parseValue) || "false".equalsIgnoreCase(parseValue))
            .map(Boolean::parseBoolean)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Boolean entity contains invalid data: " + value));
```

Comment: it is questionable if using an `Optional` is better for replacing a simple `if`... but I would, if using functional methods, use `.map` to convert to lowercase and then use the filter (but that is just my opinion)

Comment: I agree with you. if I had a simple 'if' statement, I wouldn't change it to the Optional. For the code shared in the post, there are 4 tasks (null check, checking strings if it is "true" or "false", boolean conversation, and throwing exceptions in some situations). I think these statements or similar ones should be step by step like an algorithm and 'optional ' provides it very beautifully. When I look at the code, I can see the all operations in one look with Optional.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is fine. You can make it slightly more succint, theoretically faster (though I -really- doubt it's going to matter here):

```
String input = entityDto().constantValues.get("input");
return switch (input) {
  case "true" -> true;
  case "false" -> false;
  case null, default -> throw new IllegalStateException(
     "Boolean entity contains invalid data: " + input);
};
```

Note that you may or may not want to consider `switch (input.toLowerCase())`, and if you want more strings to be valid, you can use commas, e.g. `case "true", "on", "1" -> true;`.

switch statements (a feature java has had for 30 years) are defined to throw an NPE if you attempt to switch on `null`, which is why newer forms of switch (such as switch expressions used here) also do that. However, you can `case null` to change this behaviour. This is why you have to write `case null, default` here - you want *both* `null` as well as any string value that isn't `"true"` or `"false"` to all end up at that `throw` statement.

NB: This will need java17 or perhaps even java21.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,  in this case Patterns in switch are not supported at language level '11'  appears on null and default.  No idea why, my java is 17

Comment: @user23350531 you've told your IDE and/or your build script that you want java11 compatibility, so it is dutifully reporting that you can't do this on java11. Set your iDE and/or build script to 17.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the code, I eliminated nested if statements that weren't needed.
I check to see whether the input is equal to "true" or "false" in lowercase.
It uses Boolean.parseBoolean to return the boolean representation if the condition is true.

It throws an IllegalStateException if the condition is false.
The logic required to determine if an input is "true" or "false" (case insensitive) is preserved in this version, and an exception is raised if it is not.

```
String input = entityDto().constantValues.get("input");
String message = "Boolean entity contains invalid data: " + input;

if (input != null && (input.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))) {
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
}
throw new IllegalStateException(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't another solution. Of course, you can simplify your code to this:

```java
String input = "true";
String message = "Boolean entity contains invalid data: " + input;

if (input == null || !input.toLowerCase().matches("true|false")) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(message);
}
return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
```

Comment: well, if you are already using regular expression, not need for `toLowerCase()` (but that it *personal* preference, as using `else` or not)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is an alternative.

- `(?i)` - says do case insensitive matches.
- first check for null and then test the match.

```
public static boolean validate(String input) {

    String message = ("Boolean entity contains invalid data: " + input);
    if (input != null && input.matches("(?i)true|false")) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException(message);
    
}
```